# Google Map Embed API Implementation with Markers

Tags: google-maps, embed, jquery-gmap3, google-maps-embed

I would like to mark city or area bounds using Embed API and add custom markers onto it. But I am unable to create and Map object on Embed API please help me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start), you can enter a location that you like to show  on the map, then it will create a code for you to do that. Such that:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?center=...&zoom=...&key=..."></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't want to use any Iframe

Comment: check our site http://bestorlandohousesearch.com/map i want to plot the same markers on the city region selected by user.